# Float 2 Divs to Right, One Atop the Other

Tags: html, css

Just when I think I'm beginning to get the hang of floats, I realize I'm clueless. I'm trying to the 2 divs of different widths to float to the right of my page here: [recipe page](http://www.altogether.accountsupport.com/recipes/appetizers/caviarcanapes.html)

I would like to learn and understand this and would appreciate any help. Here's a screenshot of what I'm trying to do: http://www.altogether.accountsupport.com/graphics/_recipescreenshot.gif
Thanks,
Deborah

Here's the coding I have so far

```
<article id="content">


<!-- Start Page Content -->

<div style="float:right; display:inline-block; width:270px; position:relative;">

    <div style="display:inline; float:right; border:#cccccc 1px solid; padding:5px 20px 5px 5px;">
    <div><a href="/pdf/recipes/apps/CaviarCanapes.pdf" target="_blank"><img style="float:left; padding:2px 10px 0px 0px;" src="/graphics/icon-print.gif" width="12" height="15" alt="Printable Christmas Recipes">Print Recipe &#187;</a></div>
    <div style="padding:0 0 5px 22px;">PDF file, 1 pg.</div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:right;"></div>

    <img src="/graphics/recipes/apps/CaviarCanapes.jpg" style="float:right; padding:20px 0px 10px 30px; width:250px; height:295px; clear:right;" alt="Caviar Canapes">
</div>

<a class="breadcrumb" href="/recipes.html">Christmas Recipes &#187;</a> <a class="breadcrumb" href="/recipes/appetizers.html">Appetizers &#187;</a>
<h1>Caviar Canapes with Salmon Butter</h1>

<div style="padding:0px 0px 30px 0px;">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/StarsRate/frontend/load.php?id=2&sid=0"></script>
</div>

<div class="addthispad">
<!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style addthis_16x16_style">
<a class="addthis_button_facebook"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_twitter"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_pinterest_share"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_tumblr"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_google_plusone_share"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_email"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_compact"></a><a class="addthis_counter addthis_bubble_style"></a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=altogether"></script>
<!-- AddThis Button END -->
</div>
<br><br>


<b>Ingredients</b>
<ul>
<li>1/2 cup (1 stick) unsalted butter, softened</li>
<li>3 ounces smoked salmon, finely chopped (approximately 3/4 cup)</li>
<li>2 tablespoons fresh dill, chopped</li>
<li>pinch of pepper.</li>
<li>1 baguette (long, narrow loaf of French bread)</li>
<li>5-6 ounces caviar</li>
<li>parsley for garnishing</li>
</ul><br>

<b>Directions</b>
<ol>
<li>Soften butter by bringing it to room temperature. Mix butter, chopped smoked salmon, dill and pepper in bowl and stir well.</li>
<li>Slice bread on a slant and spread salmon butter on each piece. Top with caviar and garnish with a small sprig of parsely.</li>
</ol><br>

<i>Submitted by Dirk R.</i>


<!-- End Page Content -->

   </article>
```

Comment: Please provide relevant jsfiddle

Comment: Please add some relevant code directly in your question, and explain exactly what you want the end result to be. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I looked at your page, but have no idea what the second div that you want floated is.  Please be more specific

Comment: You probably just want to add `clear: right;` to the CSS styles for the second float.

Comment: Sorry. Will try to add coding to original question. On this page though, I want the box with Print Recipe and the photo to float right, and I want the rest of the page content to the left, but the ratings and ingredients and instructions are all appearing beneath the photo.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the ingredients and directions below the picture, you should surround it with a

```
<div style="clear:both">
    <b>Ingredients</b>
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: Actually, I want them to the left. Here's a screenshot of what I'm trying to accomplish: http://www.altogether.accountsupport.com/graphics/_recipescreenshot.gif

Comment: This what you have in your original code, is not working for you?

Comment: No, I tried it again: http://www.altogether.accountsupport.com/recipes/appetizers/caviarcanapes2.html

Answer (score 0):

So after your comments, I think the problems is you have an extra closing div tag in your code here:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=altogether"></script>
<!-- AddThis Button END -->
</div>
<br><br>


<b>Ingredients</b>
<ul>
```

Remove it:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=altogether"></script>
<!-- AddThis Button END -->
<br><br>


<b>Ingredients</b>
<ul>
```

Comment: I gave that a try, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

All of this was taking place in the article section of the code. I got it to work by wrapping the star rating and social sharing in a left-floating inline-block div and then wrapping the print box and photo in a right-floating inline-block div, and having the total widths of those inline-block divs match the article width. I added HTML comments so I can easily code other pages in this section with different width photos in the right-floating div: http://www.altogetherchristmas.com/recipes/appetizers/caviarcanapes.html

I'm not sure if this is the best way to do this, but it displays correctly in all major modern browsers and on my iPad. If anyone knows a better way to do this, feel free to share. But for now, it's working.
Thanks,
Deborah

Comment: Floats actually pretty easy to grasp, you just have to remember to "clear" them on the parent element of wherever the floats are located. I have 4 methods that achieve the same thing in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/darcher/hw98P/22/ Now this was for another answer, but I don't exactly see what you were trying to achieve because the link looks like your image, so I'm providing this, but the class ".float" is where you want to look. I can add comments to a fiddle to explain what it does if you need it, just let me know.