# Float 2 divs to the right?

Tags: html, css

I checked out a [few stackoverflow posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24396108/float-2-divs-to-right-one-atop-the-other) and [other references](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/) but I can't figure out how to float both divs to the right while having them stacked on top of each other vertically (sign in on top).

From my research here are the things I concluded:

1)Floating makes the div into a block level element

2)Multiple floats "chunk" together horizontally

3) `Clear: both/right/left/etc` allows you to specify which elements should wrap around the floated element.

Here is what I am confused about:

1) How do I make different floated elements above or below each other?

Here is my JSfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/VUSKr/

Comment: Do you want to float 2 divs to right or above and below??

Comment: I couldn't see you used float in your css...

Comment: [wrap them in another div?](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/VUSKr/7/) or if you don't have any other elements, then [clear right should work](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/VUSKr/4/)

Comment: Remove float properties. It ll automatically aligned above and below if you want to float above and below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/VUSKr/6/

login and register both floar right

```
#login, #register {
    background: white;
    width: 200px;
    height: 120px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    float: right;
}
```

register clear right

```
#register{
    clear: right;
}
```

Comment: Ah, I see. So what is the point of making #register float to the right and then clearing it right after? Doesn't clear negate all floating effects? Or am I understanding this incorrectly entirely?

Comment: it tells to the browser that register will float to right side but it will have nothing in his right side (clear right side)...

Comment: clear negates of floating effects for the NEXT elements

Answer (score 0):

When you add float element you need to clear the element also. Update your CSS like below.

```
 #login, #register {
background: white;
width: 200px;
height: 120px;
border-radius: 20px;
float:right;
clear:both;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/VUSKr/8/)

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your html after `#login` close:

```
<br style="clear:right;" />
```

and in your css:

```
login, #register {
    background: white;
    width: 200px;
    height: 120px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    float:right;/* add this*/   
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VUSKr/2/)

Take a look here [clearing floats](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
#login, #register {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 white;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 120px !important;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you float a block level element it behaves like an inline-block; which is why you see them bunch together.

The simplest, and to my mind the most elegant, solution to your issue is to enclose both elements in another div and float that instead. Then you do not affect the display property of the elements you want moving.

eg:

```
.moved {float: right;}
```

An update to your Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/X993j/1/

Answer (score 0):

Use a `clear:both;` or `clear:right;` (the clear property specifies which sides of an element other floating elements are **not** allowed.) between both floating divs. Made a fiddle for you: [Float two divs to right](http://jsfiddle.net/NSLYu/)